# Sonar-qube 4.5 Timeout issue with big project

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, sonarqube

I'm using Jenkins to run sonar on all my projects. One of them have over 2 millions line of code and started to produce a timeout error when connecting to sonar (posted bellow is the jenkins build log):

```html
[JENKINS] Archiving /app/users/jenkins/jobs/*****RunSonar/workspace/******/pom.xml to com.****.***.****/****Gui/9.1.0/****Gui-9.1.0.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /app/users/jenkins/jobs/****_****Gui_RunSonar/workspace/****Gui/target/****Gui.war to com.****.***.****/****Gui/9.1.0/****Gui-9.1.0.war
channel stopped
[workspace] $ /app/tools/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin/mvn -f /app/users/jenkins/jobs/****_****Gui_RunSonar/workspace/****Gui/pom.xml -Dgitbranch=my_development -e -B sonar:sonar -Dsonar.preview.readTimeout=90000 -Dsonar.jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@mydb:1521:orcl ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=https://********/sonar/ -Dsonar.branch=$gitbranch ******** ********
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.****.***.****:****Gui:war:9.1.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin is missing. @ line 408, column 23
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ****Gui 9.1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.4 has been relocated to org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.4
[WARNING] The artifact aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.5.4 has been relocated to org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.5.4
[WARNING] The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) @ ****Gui ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 34.033 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-14T10:31:44+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/148M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) on project ****Gui: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar failed: SonarQube server can not be reached at https://********/sonar. Please check the parameter 'sonar.host.url'. connect timed out -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) on project *******: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar failed: SonarQube server can not be reached at https://********/sonar. Please check the parameter 'sonar.host.url'.
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar failed: SonarQube server can not be reached at https://*********/sonar. Please check the parameter 'sonar.host.url'.
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:144)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
 ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SonarQube server can not be reached at https://********/sonar. Please check the parameter 'sonar.host.url'.
 at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.ServerMetadata.getVersion(ServerMetadata.java:70)
 at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.ServerMetadata.logSettings(ServerMetadata.java:84)
 at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:128)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
 ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
 at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
 at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.ServerMetadata.getConnection(ServerMetadata.java:119)
 at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.ServerMetadata.remoteContent(ServerMetadata.java:91)
 at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.ServerMetadata.getVersion(ServerMetadata.java:66)
 ... 23 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
Sonar analysis completed: FAILURE
```

I'm pretty sure the sonar.host.url is correct because all of my other jobs in jenkins that run sonar are working. I already tried to use the "sonar.preview.readTimeout" property but with no success. Sonar produces no log.

Does anyone have any idea how to run sonar to avoid this problem?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with localhost instead and see if its able to connect to localhost at the very least?  For localhost you need to have sonar server running locally of course.